# How to get the Picking order from Packing order in 3 step delivery?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

**Odoo 14 Community Edition**

I have set the configuration as Pick > Pack > Ship.

The Picking is done. Now I am in Packing, but I would like to get the `stock_picking` object of the Picking, which is the object of its previous step of delivery.

How to refer to that specific Pick object from Pack?

Note: The `id` of the Pick and Pack are not always adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you're using the warehouse `delivery_steps = pick_pack_ship` and have completed the pick picking step, the direct relationship between `stock.picking` objects isn't readily available. However, Odoo conveniently stores this information in the `stock.move` records.

To access the pick-picking ID from the pack picking move, you can make use of the `move_orig_ids` field. This field contains the moves associated with the initial pick picking. Once you have the move information, obtaining the `picking_id` is straightforward.

Here's the approach:

```
# Assuming 'self' refers to the current Pack object

# Retrieve the move associated with the pack picking
pack_move = self.move_ids_without_package

# Access the move_orig_ids field to get the pick picking move
pick_move = pack_move.move_orig_ids

# Now, the pick picking ID is accessible through the picking_id field of pick_move
pick_picking_id = pick_move.picking_id.id
```

This method capitalizes on Odoo's underlying structure, using stock moves as a link between different picking stages. By extracting the information from the `move_orig_ids` field, you gain access to the pick picking ID.

I trust this explanation proves useful for your scenario. If you have further queries, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: All of my `stock.move.line`'s `result_package_id` are `null`. I don't know why, but it seems impossible to use this technique to link that way.

Comment: if you use the `put in pack` button on the picking, it should have the result_package_id on your stock move line.

Comment: No, I did not use the button.

Comment: oh ok, you mean warehouse delivery_steps = pick_pack_ship, I have updated the answer, and hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You will find the connections on the moves (`stock.move`, i think the field's name is `move_lines`) of the pickings.

On the model `stock.move` you have to fields representating the connections: `move_orig_ids` and `move_dest_ids`. Both are m2m fields to model `stock.move`, where you will find the picking on field `picking_id`.

Comment: I find `move_orig_ids` from Pack and I got all of the Packs. The `picking_id` in there does lead to its corresponding Picking. However, I only want the Pick that leads to this Pack. Right now, I cannot distinguish which Pack is this current Pack from `move_orig_ids` because it gives me all of the associated Packs.